# Segmentation fault at passing array of integers to function

Tags: c, linux, pointers

I have pasted the code here, at the statement `*stack_ptr->s3++ = element;`
segmentation fault is occurring. Can you please let me know what should I change to eliminate the error?

```
typedef int stack_elmnt_int;
typedef struct {
  stack_elmnt *s1;
  stack_elmnt_int *s3;
  int length;
  int top;
} stack;


int push_stack_int(stack *stack_ptr, stack_elmnt_int element)
{
    int i=0;

    if (stack_full(stack_ptr))
        printf("\nStack is full.");
    else{
        *stack_ptr->s3++ = element;
    }
}
void main()
{
    int arr[128], arr_num = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    //after input from user to arr
    //partial code pasted here

    for(i=0;i<arr_num ;i++)
        push_stack_int(&stack_1,arr[i]);
}
```

Comment: Have you initialized `s3`?

Comment: We need to see the full code, especially the declaration of stack_1, since it is probably not being initialized properly.

Comment: segfault is at `*stack_ptr->s3++ = element;` because you don't allocate memory for `s3`.

Comment: Where do you initialize the s3 pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> statement `(*stack_ptr->s3++ = element;)` segmentation fault is occuring,

Probably you don't allocate memory for `s3`.

```
 *stack_ptr->s3++ = element;
              ^ 
              | assigning to garbage location
```

> Can you please let me know what should I change to eliminate the error?

In main() function after declaration of `stack_1` allocate memory for `s3` ( you should allocate memory for `s1` also ), do like:

```
stack_1.s3 = calloc(MAX_NUMBER_OF_ELEMENT, sizeof( stack_elmnt_int));
```

Additionally,  you should not increment `s3` pointer. (you will loss starting address) do like:

```
stack_ptr->s3[top++] = element;
```

Comment: Thanks,
After asking question I tried out this, stack_ptr->s3[top++] = element;
and it worked.
thanks

Comment: @Mike your welcom Mike!, understand `++` is postfix so first `element` assigned to index with current value of `top` then after `++` performed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check that both `stack_ptr` and `stack_ptr->s3` have had memory allocated and been initialized previously in your code.